# Confusion about SQL Server snapshot isolation and how to use it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am newbie to MS Sql Server. Just a few months experience maintaining SQL Server SPs. I am reading up about transaction isolation levels for optimising an SP and am quite confused. Please help me with below questions:

1. If I run DBCC useroptions in ClientDB, the default value for isolation level is 'read committed'. Does this mean the DB is set to isolation level is set to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON ?
2. Is  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (at transaction level) same as SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON (at DB level)? By this I mean that IF my DB has SNAPSHOT enabled, then can I set isolation level in my SP and process data accordingly?
3. is ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION similar to above?
4. I have an SP which starts off with a very long running SELECT statement that also dumps it's contents into a temp table. Then uses the temp table to UPDATE/INSERT base table. There are about 8 mil records being selected and dumped into temp table, then a similar number of total rows updated/inserted. The problem we are facing is that this SP takes up too much disk space.
   It is a client DB and we do not have permissions to check disk space/log size etc in the DB. So I do not know if the tempDB/tempDB-log is taking up this disk space or clientDB/clientDB-log is. But the disk space can reduce by as much as 10GB at one go! This causes the transaction log to run out of disk space (as disk is full) and SP errors out.
   If I use SNAPSHOT isolation level, will this disk space get even more affected? as it uses tempDB to versionize the data?
5. What I really want to do is this:
   SET transaction isolation level to SNAPSHOT. Then do the SELECT into Temp table. Then BEGIN TRANSACTION  and update/insert base table for say ... 1 mil records. Do this in a LOOP until all records processed. Then END TRANSACTION. Do you think this is a good idea? Should the initial SELECT be kept out of the TRANSACTION? Will this help in reducing the load on the transaction logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An isolation level of "read committed" isn't the same thing as setting READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON. Setting READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON sets the default isolation level for *all* queries. A query or procedure that then uses "read committed" isolation level *does* use snapshot isolation. See [Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in Books Online.

> When the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option is set ON, read
>   committed isolation uses row versioning to provide statement-level
>   read consistency. Read operations require only SCH-S table level locks
>   and no page or row locks. When the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database
>   option is set OFF, which is the default setting, read committed
>   isolation behaves as it did in earlier versions of SQL Server. Both
>   implementations meet the ANSI definition of read committed isolation.

ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION doesn't change the default isolation level. It lets each query or procedure use snapshot isolation if you want it to. Each query that you want to use snapshot isolation needs to SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT. On big systems, if you want to use snapshot isolation, you *probably* want this rather than changing the default isolation level with READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT.

A database configured to use snapshot isolation does take more disk space.

Think about moving the log files to a bigger disk.

Comment: Mike: Thank you for your answer. Apologies for replying late as I got stuck in other issues.

Comment: Increasing log sizes is not an option as I have no control over the DB. Also checked that SNAPSHOT ISOLATION is turned OFF in the DB as well as in production. So now that is not an option. So, to ask further, point #5 in my question above is about leaving the initial query out of the TRAN/COMMIT routine. Will that in any way help with using up lesser tempDB? (As temp table is being used to store query output) Or in any other way make the transaction more efficient?

Comment: I don't think inserting a million rows at a time in a loop will help you. Inserting a million rows at a time *and committing them* might help, but if your process can tolerate that kind of risk, I'd consider updating the base tables directly instead. Also, SELECT INTO statements can be [minimally logged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I have looked into minimal logging and I think this will help me resolve this. Will post once I can make this work. Many thanks for pointing it out.